# How do you get the "Amped up" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

The description says "share a link to a question on social media that gets 5 clicks".

I've tweeted a question that got over 5 clicks. I've posted a share link in chat that also got over 5 clicks. Both of these had my user ID number in it and were clicked by different people.

I watched in real life as the twitter link was clicked, by family and friends, on different computers each time. It's not a problem of the same IP.  (no wifi network overlap either)

Why haven't I gotten the hat? For the record, it's been almost an hour by now, so it's not hat lag causing the problem.

To clarify: the clicks were opening the share link in the browser, which redirected to the full url. [The link was this.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15244/46271)

Comment: What do you define "click" as?

Comment: @StephenLeppik the short link opening in the browser and redirecting to the long url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amped Up requires that 5 distinct users click on a link to a question that you share.  At this moment, I'm showing that you haven't had a link clicked by 5 distinct users since the start of Winter Bash which is why you haven't gotten the hat...yet.

Comment: Do they have to be registered users or something?

Comment: Okay, voting this above my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It doesn't appear to be limited to registered users.

Comment: Strange, I initially tried both Tor and VPN relays, but after a while I gave up and posted links in chat and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "click" means the same as for the "announcer" badge—it has to be visited by 5 different IP addresses. For example, I posted a link in SOCVR, and got the badge fairly quickly.

Comment: That's not it. They were clicked by different people, no chance of being that.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ are you sure that it was 5 separate IP addresses though?

Comment: Yes. In the twitter link, I watched friends and family click the link, all from different computers/phones.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ on different wi-fi networks?

Comment: Yeah. 3 phones that were connected by cell service, and two different wifi networks.

Comment: Wouldn't this count as serial-voting?

Comment: @PythonMaster serial-viewing, not serial-voting.